# can any one tell me the name of alert view that should do the works of **C# show dialog** 

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, alerts

can any one tell me the name of alert view that should do the works of   **C# show dialog** .
other actions will not work without dismissing it(EVEN DELEGATES ALSO).

Comment: basically i am a c# programmer.i don't what's the reason of -1 mark.

Answer (score 1):

Modal dialogs in Windows (in any language) and in iOS are fundamentally different.

On Windows, a modal dialog (and in particular the `ShowDialog` method) behaves like a function call that will only return when the dialog is closed. Your app will naturally wait until the your has made his decision.

On iOS, `presentModalViewController` (or `[UIAlertView show]`) almost immediately return. You can registered a delegate that will be notified when the dialog is closed. But if your app is supposed to wait only the user has chosen something in the dialog, then you have to implement the waiting yourself.

Answer (score 0):

As far as know, You have to do this manually. You can lock your task when the alert is shown and then unlock it again when it is dismissed getting help from these posts.

[is there a way to pause an NSTHread indefinitely and have it resumed from another thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230569/is-there-a-way-to-pause-an-nsthread-indefinitely-and-have-it-resumed-from-another)

[How to pause an NSThread until notified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557070/how-to-pause-an-nsthread-until-notified)

Comment: You don't want to pause the current thread as it's the main thread and the only UI thread. Pausing it will completely freeze the app.